# Printing parameters in win32 console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here's my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    for (int i = 1;i<argc;i++) printf("Argument %d:%s\n",i,argv[i]);
    // output = Argument 1:param

    for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) cout << "Argument " << k << ": " << argv[k];
    // output =  Argument 1: 00BF5878
    return(0);
}
```

My question is: why do I see different outputs on cout and printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see an address in the output from `cout` because you have built the program with `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` defined. Probably by way of a setting in a Visual Studio project. Then `_tmain` expands to MIcrosoft's non-standard `wmain`, and `_TCHAR` expands to `wchar_t`.

And `cout` doesn't know how that a pointer to `wchar_t` is supposed to point to a null-terminated string of wide characters.

I am not sure why that doesn't happen with `printf`. Lemme check.

---

OK I have checked and your `printf` is *not* printing "param" as you indicate it does.

Here's the corrected code I checked with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    for( int i = 0;i < argc; ++i )
    {
        printf("printf Argument %d:%s\n",i,argv[i]);
    }

    for( int i = 0;  i < argc;  ++i )
    {
        cout << "cout Argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp /D _UNICODE
foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> foo param
printf Argument 0:f
printf Argument 1:p
cout Argument 0: 004F9A9C
cout Argument 1: 004F9AA4

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

In other words, the apparent conundrum is entirely caused by your inaccurate reporting of results.

---

Solution: instead of using Microsoft's non-standard `wmain`, and in particular instead of using the now totally meaningless Windows 9x support macros!, use a **standard C++ `main`**.

Comment: If that was his problem, the `printf` would break because he would try to print a wchar_t string via the `printf` as a `char` string.

Comment: There is a problem with _TCHAR* argv[]. Changed it to const char* and now it cout normally.

Comment: I didn't say it prints "param". I used word param as global parameter that I input. If I run the program with "-v" it prints "-v". So this part works as expected.

Comment: His reporting is accurate. He probably did not compile with `/D_UNICODE`.

Comment: Anyway.. you're right. I should switch to c++ standards and not using microsoft's mutation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `printf` takes the contents of the parameters and *forces* the data to match the format specifier.  The content of `argv[i]` will be treated as a nul terminated string because of the `%s` format specifier.

The `cout` in conjunction with the stream insertion operator will output based on the type of the parameter.  The compiler will search all the `operator<<()` methods for `cout` and choose the one the best matches the parameter.

In your case, the compiler is looking for the method `operator<<(TCHAR *)` and didn't find an exact match.  Instead, the compiler recognized that the parameter was a pointer and chose `operator<<(void *)` which prints out a pointer.

Try defining `operator<<(TCHAR*)` and see what happens.